# Memory Game Two Players Java Client Server

Tags: java, server, applet, client

This Memory Game as 2 players/clients, one is 'X' other is 'O'. My game uses 4x4 grid, filled with random numbers on pairs (1 to 8), when the first player start it already as the grid filled with random numbers, but when i start second player the grid is filled with different numbers, i want random equal numbers in both two players grids.

Do i have to change the code on the function setArrayListText(), or add/modify some instances of code?

Cliente.java (Client)

```
public class Cliente extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable
{
    ...    
    private JPanel boardPanel, panel2;
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    private JPanel gamePnl = new JPanel();
    ...
    public void start2() 
    {
        try 
        {
            connection  = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 5000 );
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            inputThread = new Thread( this );
            inputThread.start();

            MsgIdt msg = new MsgIdt();
            msg.envia(output);
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
    public void createGUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    ...

    public void createJPanels()
    {
        gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        TrataRato tr = new TrataRato();
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);              
            gameBtn[i].addMouseListener(tr);      
        }  
   ...  
    }

    // You will need to fit this properly in your client class
    public List<Integer> listReciever() throws IOException
    {  
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = input.readInt(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lista.add(input.readInt());
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Servidor.java (Server)

```
  public class Servidor extends JFrame 
  {
       private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

       public Servidor () 
       {
            super( "Tic-Tac-Toe Server" );
            Container cont = getContentPane();
            board = new byte[9];
            players = new Player[2];
            currentPlayer = 0;
            try
            {
                server = new ServerSocket(5000, 2 );
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit( 1 );
            }
            output = new TextArea(10, 30);
            output.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(output);
            cont.add( "Center", sp);
            display("Tic-Tac-Toe Server running.");
            addWindowListener(new ProcessaJanela());
            setVisible(true);
            pack();
       }

       public void execute() 
       {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < players.length; i++ ) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    players[i] = new Player( server.accept(), this, i );
                    players[i].start();
                    ++numberOfPlayers;
                } 
                catch ( IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit( 1 );
                }
            }
            setTurn();
       }

       public int getNumberOfPlayers() 
       {
            return numberOfPlayers;
       }

       public int getCurrentPlayer() 
       {
            return currentPlayer;
       }

       public int getWinner() 
       {
            return winner;
       }

       public boolean getGameOver()
       {
            return gameOver;
       }

       public void setArrayListText() // generates random numbers
       { 
           java.util.List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
           Collections.shuffle(lista);
           gameList.addAll(lista);
       }    
       public void gridclients() throws IOException
       {
            players[0].sendList(gameList);
            players[1].sendList(gameList);
       }

       public void setTurn()
       {
            try
            {          
                players[currentPlayer].setTurn("OK");
                players[(currentPlayer == 0 ? 1 : 0 )].setTurn("NOK");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Player.java

```
public class Player extends Thread 
{
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    Servidor control;
    Socket connection;
    ObjectInputStream input;    //por no protocolo as msgs serem da classe Object
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    int number;
    char mark;

    public Player(Socket s, Servidor t, int num ) 
    {
        connection = s;
        control = t;
        number = num;
        mark = ( num == 0 ? 'X' : 'O' );
        try
        {
            input   = new ObjectInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );
            output  = new ObjectOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }  
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            while( !control.getGameOver() ) 
            {
                processaMsg(Protocolo.recebe(input));
            }
            connection.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }  

    public void sendList(List<Integer> gameList) throws IOException 
    { 
        output.writeInt(gameList.size()); 
        for(int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++)
        {
            output.writeInt(gameList.get(i)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want the same random sequence in both client, you have to generate it outside of client's code and then pass it into both clients. Either in the constructor of the client or in some setter like method. Basically the setArrayListText() code has to be executed outside the client

Comment: Ok setArrayListText() code is now in the server. But how i send it to both players ? The Grids are both empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are shuffling at client side, when you have 2 clients running they run separately from each other and shuffle will give you different results, so you should transfer shuffling logic on server, server will generate grid and then send it to both players.

I don't like using ObjectOutputStream, especially when sending more complex objects, that approach is prone to big mistakes and failures, its always better to use raw data, and send it using DataOutputStream/DataInputStream.

Assuming that your client handler on server side is Player class since you are sending Socket there

Server method for sending list should be inside `Player` class:

```
public void sendList(List<Integer> gameList) throws IOException {
   output.writeInt(gameList.size()); 
   for(int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++){
       output.writeInt(gameList.get(i)); 
   }
}
```

Then you will call `sendList` for both players in `Servidor class` like this:

```
 player[0].sendList(gameList);
 player[1].sendList(gameList);
```

Client receiving:

```
// You will need to fit this properly in your client class
public List<Integer> listReciever(){  
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int size = input.readInt(); 
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       list.add(input.readInt());
}
```

Comment: Ok setArrayListText() code is now in the server. But how i send it to both players ? The Grids are both empty.

Comment: Could you provide code that you are using for communication between client and server, without code its hard to give you proper answer since there are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: Also 1 suggestion, if you are new to client-server then it is better to start with something simple, like sending 2 numbers to server from client, and then send the sum from server back to client. Once you get grasp you can slowly add new things.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, i added all the code you propose, but for some reason the Grids are both empty, i don't know if it sends the same grid to both players, i can tell that the grid is always empty, with a JButton. Not really sure if the Client receiving is properly fitted in my client class.

Comment: Try adding output.flush() after each writing, use debugger to check values, also when receiving from server you most likely want to have some loop, but I again would suggest you to first make something simpler in other to understand how it works.